# Logging multiline messages in heroku

Tags: node.js, logging, heroku

I'm developing an application using NodeJS and deployed in Heroku.

I need to log multi-line messages (eg. stacktraces and other multiline information) but would like to retain them as one log message each.

The problem is that when using `console.log` (or any framework that uses `console.log`/`stdout`) with a multiline message it's interpreted like multiple messages by Heroku (one message per each line in the original message).

I think the problem lies in that Heroku reads the messages from the process' `stdout` and cannot distinguish between the line feeds (`LF`/`CR`) in one message or the line feeds in multiple messages and thus creates one message per line.

I've tried to send the messages directly to syslog (using [ain2](https://npmjs.org/package/ain2)) instead of to stdout and it works with multiline messages but only on my local environment.

I'd like to do the same thing in Heroku which uses logplex/syslog? but haven't been able to get my messages logged when using syslog with default params (localhost, UDP, port 514).

Is there any other way to log multiline messages in Heroku that works? Is this a shortfall in the platform?

Answer (score 0):

I am not even sure how successful you'll be with stack traces, since eventually this is `syslog`-based, and Heroku might have a limit on the length of a single `syslog` line. Not sure, though, and certainly wouldn't know about the limit.

What you can do is replace every `\n` with `\n>>>` (that is: start every continuation line with ">>>"), and then parse this accordingly in your log-processing code.

Comment: Thanks, I've tested with a few normal message sizes and seems ok. If I go with longer messages (around 2KB) they seem to get trimmed. But that's going to happen anyway with or without line feeds I pressume.

Comment: The replace option could be an option but still looking for an option that doesn't require any pre/post-processing and that makes the messages more human readable.