# AWS CloudWatch multiline log message from Heroku

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Running **Node.js** on **Heroku**.

The app's log messages are exported to **AWS CloudWatch**, by using the following `aws-cloudwatch-forwarder` NPM library (which brilliantly wraps the node app and sends everything to **AWS CloudWatch**).

Everything is perfect except the fact that multi-line log messages are broken into separate log messages.

For example:

```
aaa = {
  "APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL": "true",
  "AWS_REGION": "eu-west-3",
}
```

is being reported to AWS CloudWatch like this:

```
11:07:34    aaa = {
11:07:34      "APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL": "true",
11:07:34      "AWS_REGION": "eu-west-3",
11:07:34    }
```

I've tried the following non-working solutions:

1. Replacing every `'\n'` with `'\n>>>'` (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492312/logging-multiline-messages-in-heroku)).
2. Replacing every `'\n'` with `'\n\t'` or `'\n ' /*mind the space*/` (according to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html)).
3. Replacing every `'\n'` with `'\r'` (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260126/what-are-the-differences-between-char-literals-n-and-r-in-java)).
4. Saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190400/heroku-python-flask-web-app-truncating-log-messages-to-only-one-line) unanswered question.
5. Also looked everywhere online.

**Does anyone knows how to send the message as one multi-line message???** like this:

```
11:07:34    aaa = {
  "APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL": "true",
  "AWS_REGION": "eu-west-3",
}
```